# Nodes of orientation of electron orbitals

Tags: quantum-chemistry

[image]
As you can see the orientation of 2 p orbital there is a nodal plane in between the electron density pictures.... So doesn't the electron move from left to right side in2 p X orbital. 
I think that electrons moved around the nucleus in circular paths

Comment: Electrons don't move in circular paths. That's just an oversimplified model used to explain emission spectra.

Comment: You are trying to connect the particle and wave picture into one thing. Don't  do that! Those are two *different* perspectives on the same thing. The electron does not "move around in its orbital". The orbital is the electron (in its wave function description).